# Physical memory analysis of ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

According to ReactJS' documentation "React creates an **in-memory data structure cache**, computes the resulting differences, and then updates the browser's displayed DOM efficiently".

My questions are:

1. Is the in-memory data structure cache on the server side?
2. If so, what is the solution to scale React servers beyond a single instance?
3. Can we configure React so that it uses cookie or some other storage instead of in-memory data structure cache?
4. Do you have to pin browser sessions to the same server (I am planning to have multiple servers)?

Comment: it's mainly the virtual DOM that gets rerendered on state changes, when a component renders differently, it gets replaced in the real dom. Personally, I think these are client side changes, but I haven't worked with the serverside version of ReactJ

Comment: @Icepickle - That's true, but the virtual DOM is changed when the state changes, and this state is in-memory data structure cache. So is this cache on the server side? If it is, what would happen when we switch servers?

Comment: React is a written in javascript and hence it has to run inside an javascript engine. If it is a simple website, the mostly the react code runs on users browser(like chrome). This has nothing to do with server. Even if you do a SSR, i dn think i would worry about server unless i'm serving millions of request per second.

Comment: ReactJS (and any browser using your app) don't use *physical* memory directly. It needs an OS and has a [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The " in-memory data structure cache" referred to is the Virtual DOM and it resides in the client, specifically, the browser's Javascript engine. It keeps track of all your components and their states. When some component changes state, due to user interaction, API calls to server, etc, React checks the Virtual DOM to determine which components are affected by this particular state change, and makes the minimum required changes to the DOM. This is what makes React so performant for creating complex dynamic UIs.

I hope that answers your first question, leaving you not having to worry about the other questions :)